# SagePay - 400 - Incorrect request format

Tags: opayo

I'm trying to formulate a payment via Node.js using request-promise library. I'm getting this error:

```
400 - {"description":"Incorrect request format","code":1000}
```

Currently using sandbox, my code is as follows:

```
    const postData = JSON.stringify({
      "transactionType": "Payment",
      "paymentMethod": {
        "card": {
          "merchantSessionKey": merchantSessionKey,
          "cardIdentifier": cardIdentifier
        }
      },
      "vendorTxCode": `demotransaction-${time}`,
      "amount": parseInt(baseGrandTotal, 10),
      "currency": baseCurrencyCode,
      "description": "Demo transaction",
      "customerFirstName": customer.address_billing.firstname,
      "customerLastName": customer.address_billing.lastname,
      "billingAddress": {
        "address1": customer.address_billing.street[0],
        "city": customer.address_billing.city,
        "postalCode": customer.address_billing.postcode,
        "country": customer.address_billing.country_id
      }
    });

    const SagePayment = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const requestOptions = {
        method: 'POST',
        uri: 'https://pi-test.sagepay.com/api/v1/transactions',
        headers: {
          'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          Authorization: 'Basic aEpZeHN3N0hMYmo0MGNCOHVkRVM4Q0RSRkxodUo4RzU0TzZyRHBVWHZFNmhZRHJyaWE6bzJpSFNyRnliWU1acG1XT1FNdWhzWFA1MlY0ZkJ0cHVTRHNocktEU1dzQlkxT2lONmh3ZDlLYjEyejRqNVVzNXU='
        },
        body: postData,
        json: true
      };

      rp(requestOptions)
        .then(data => {
          resolve(data);
        })
        .catch(err => {
          reject(err);
        });
    });
```

In the full response I can see I'm inserting valid JSON into the body. So I'm very confused what the problem is. I've checked the JSON I'm providing against the API docs too and cannot see an obvious problem.

Example of JSON body:

```
{
    "transactionType": "Payment",
    "paymentMethod": {
        "card": {
            "merchantSessionKey": "365636356",
            "cardIdentifier": "365636356"
        }
    },
    "vendorTxCode": "demotransaction-1548349070589",
    "amount": 142,
    "currency": "GBP",
    "description": "Demo transaction",
    "customerFirstName": "Name",
    "customerLastName": "Lastname",
    "billingAddress": {
        "address1": "street",
        "city": "city",
        "postalCode": "postcode",
        "country": "GB"
    }
}
```